# How To Show Android Action Bar in WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview, android-actionbar

How would one go about enabling the ActionBar in a webview.  My current code goes straight to loading the page in a web browser and skips all of my other activity logic, but I'm not sure why.

**Main Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("My Page");
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl(http://www.google.com);
}
```

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried creating a dialog to show the webview, but that also proved unsuccessful.
Thanks!

Comment: If you use Android4, just call the `setTheme` before `setContentView`. But if you use some custom action bar for older versions, this will not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I found the answer to my problem, but it was more of a technicality than anything.

The problem was that the link was a redirect page, so the built in web-browser app was hijacking my session, adding this into my onCreate method solved it.

Thanks for the replies though!

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> How would one go about enabling the ActionBar in a webview.

You don't, any more than you "enable the ActionBar" in a `Button`. An action bar is a UI component of an activity, not a widget.

> My current code goes straight to loading the page in a web browser and skips all of my other activity logic, but I'm not sure why.

I am fairly certain that it is executing all statements of your `onCreate()`. If you use a debugger, you can watch that for yourself.

If your real problem is that the action bar is not appearing, make sure that you:

- have your target SDK version in the manifest set to 11 or higher
- have your activity theme set to a Sherlock them, per [the ActionBarSherlock documentation](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html)

Comment: I am using SherlockAction bar, but what I want to accomplish basically is to have the ActionBar appear on the webview, or have the webview be a part of the activity with room for the bar at the top.

Comment: @user983010: If the action bar is showing up, that is what you get. "have the ActionBar appear on the webview" -- I have no idea what that means. "have the webview be a part of the activity with room for the bar at the top" -- that is already handled for you by `SherlockActivity` and kin.